Why isn't there a nice vector integration theory on smooth manifolds?
I'm very unfamiliar with differential geometry, but recently I'm forced to learn it. One thing I've noticed is it seems differential forms only works nicely for real valued functions defined on smooth manifolds (maybe this claim is already wrong, I'm not sure). Suppose $M^n$ is a smooth manifold and there is a vector-valued function $f: M^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ defined on it. When should I expect an integration of $f$ on $M^n$ would make sense? Intuitively it seems there should be a general notion. But I can't find it. I'm not looking for $f$ inner-product with the normal vector as the integrand. Thanks in advance.

You integrate $f$ by integrating each of its $m$ components separately.  There is no problem at all.

@MikhailKatz Is it that simple??

As simple as $\tau$ (though I am over a week late).  MK

Yes integration of vector-valued (or even Banach-space-valued) functions is perfectly fine if you have a measure to integrate against (e.g. the Riemannian measure from a Riemannian metric) or if you have a specific volume form so that you can convert to a vector-valued $n$-form. However what we cannot do is integrate vector-bundle-valued objects, because they take values in different vector spaces, so for example you cannot integrate a vector field on a manifold (unless there exists, and you fix, a trivialization of its tangent bundle).
